# Able to store data in redux, but failed to view it in front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, redux, redux-toolkit

Working on a form to store values in redux store using redux-toolkit. Able to log values in the redux dev tools, but the typed values entered in the form are not visible and the validations are not working for the input fields.

**userSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    name: null,
    email: null,
    phone: null,
    url: null,
    message: null
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    saveUser: (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload?.name;
      state.email = action.payload?.email;
      state.phone = action.payload?.phone;
      state.url = action.payload?.url;
      state.message = action.payload?.message;
    }
  }
})

export const { saveUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../Slice/userSlice';

export const store = configureStore ({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer
  }
});
```

**Contact.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ContactForm from '../../Forms/ContactForm';
  
function Contact() {    
    return(
        <div className="columns">
            <ContactForm />
        </div>
    )
}
  
export default Contact;
```

**ContactForm.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import validate from '../Validations/validate';
import renderTextArea from '../Fields/TextAreaInput/renderTextArea';
import renderField from '../Fields/TextInput/renderField';
import './ContactForm.css';
import { saveUser } from '../Slice/userSlice';

function ContactForm() {
    const formContainer = useRef(null);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
      name: null,
      email: null,
      phone: null,
      url: null,
      message: null
    });

    const handleChange = e => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
      console.log("user", user)
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
      console.log(user, "submit data")
      e.preventDefault();
      dispatch(saveUser((user)));
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">  
          <form id="contact" ref={formContainer} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            <fieldset>
              <Field name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your full name" component={renderField} onChange={handleChange} />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <Field name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" component={renderField} onChange={handleChange} />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <Field name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your phone number" component={renderField} onChange={handleChange} />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <Field placeholder="Your Web Site" type="url" name="url" component={renderField} onChange={handleChange} />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <Field name="message" component={renderTextArea} id="message" placeholder="Enter your message here..." rows={4} onChange={handleChange} />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'contact',
    validate,
})(ContactForm);
```

**validate.js**

```
const validate = val => {
    const errors = {}
    if (!val.name) {
      errors.name = 'Required';
    } else if(!/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(val.name)) {
      errors.name = 'Invalid Name';
    }
    if (!val.email) {
      errors.email = 'Required';
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(val.email)) {
      errors.email = 'Invalid email address';
    }
    if (!val.phone) {
      errors.phone = 'Required';
    } else if (val.phone.length !== 10) {
      if(/[^0-9]/.test(val.phone)) {
        errors.phone = 'Phone number must be 10 characters'
      } else {
        errors.phone = 'Invalid phone number'
      }
    } 
    if(!val.url) {
      val.url = !val.url ? "" : val.url;
    }
    if (!val.message) {
      val.message = !val.message ? "" : val.message;
    }
    return errors;
}

export default validate;
```

Screenshots for reference

[Form UI after typing inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkRwt.png)

[Redux Dev Tools (after clicking on submit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0kLc.png)